# Exporting an object's edge length and edge angle data to CSV file

Tags: export, csv

is there a way of being able to export an object's edge length and edge angles to a CSV file?

I have created an object with some 200 triangulated faces and I would like to export the information about its edge length and edge angle to a CSV file that can be used to build the object (not 3D print).

I'm relatively new to blender. I'm using Version 2.93.5 (2.93.5 2021-10-06)
I have tried to find an answer unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2):

here's something using bmesh to calc edge and angle between faces, it should work in 2.93
angle is signed and in radians, it fallbacks to 10 if edge doesn’t have 2 faces, see I rounded values too...

you may want to change those things, see bmesh docs if you needed something else I didn't understand

```
import bpy, bmesh, csv
rows = []

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

for i, e in enumerate(bm.edges):
    len = round(e.calc_length(), 5)
    ang = round(e.calc_face_angle_signed(10), 5) # use fallback=10 for Blender 3
    rows.append([i, len, ang])
bm.free()

with open('C:\\tmp\\egdes.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for r in rows: writer.writerow(r)
```

Comment: Thank you alambre, I'll try it out